# Angular Resource Setup for Web Api 2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

So I have my api controller:

```
public BlogController
{
    public Blog[] Get()
    {
        return context.Blogs.ToArray();
    }

    public Blog Get(Guid id)
    {
        return context.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id.Equals(id));
    }
}
```

How do I setup my Angular resource to mimic this?

I started off with this:

```
angular.module('spaTestApp.home.services', [])
    .factory('blogRepository', ['$resource', function($resource) {
            return {
                get: function() {
                    return $resource('/api/Blogs').query();
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Then I thought I might need to do this instead:

```
angular.module('spaTestApp.home.services', [])
        .factory('blogRepository', ['$resource', function($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/Blogs/:id', {}, {
                query: {method:'GET', params:{id:'WHAT_GOES_HERE'}, isArray:true}
            });
        }]);
```

I'm not entirely sure what goes in `WHAT_GOES_HERE`, and then how to call the get, I assume it would be:

```
blogRepository.query($selectedId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to provide the selected value at the resource definition time, so you can remove it from the `$resource` configuration object.

Instead when you call the method you do

`blogRepository.query({id:$selectedId});`

Comment: The route has been configured when you defined the route. It would just replace the template id with the value from the object which has same name property. Try it.

Comment: so my resource looks like this: `$resource('/api/Blogs/:id')`

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the angular docs, it explains where you would do this. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

There is a section that talks about the user resource which like what is below:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
  var user = User.get({id:123}, function() {
    user.abc = true;
    user.$save();
  });
```

When using a factory you could go the route below

```
 app.factory('Blog', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/v1/blogs/:id', {id: '@id'});
    }
 ]);
```

Or if you want to add the update and query part

```
app.factory('Blog', ['$resource', function($resource) {
   return $resource('/api/v1/blogs/:id', {id: '@id'},
       {
           'update': { method:'PUT' }
           'query':  { method:'GET', isArray:true},
       });
   }
]);
```

Then when calling a get

```
Blog.get({id: $scope.selectedId});
```

Or using the collection call

```
Blog.query();
```

Which can be also be handled like a promise

```
Blog.get({id: $scope.selectedId})
   .$promise.then(function(response){
     //do something with response
   });
```

If you want to grab a collection of resources

```
$scope.blogs; //If this is your blogs collection

Blog.get()
   .$promise.then(function(response){
       $scope.blogs = response;
   });
```

Keep in mind, console.log(response) will return an array with 2 extra components which is the promise is resolved and the $promise. Once you set it to your scope variable, it will only be an array of resources.